# java ternary operator and lazy evaluation

Tags: java, ternary-operator, operator-precedence

I'm trying to simplify, once and for all, a common condition:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    boolean a = true;
    boolean b = false;
    boolean c = true;

    boolean t1 = (a && b) || (!a && c);
    boolean t2 = a ? b : c;

    System.out.println(t1);
    System.out.println(t2);
}
```

where, obviously, `t1` and `t2` are equivalent.

**Is there a way, using operator precedence, to express the condition without using ternary operator and evaluating `a` just one time?**

Thanks

---

real world example:

```
if(execution.isActive() ? !Objects.equals(sourceStep, currentStep) : sourceStep != null)
{
    throw new IllegalStateException("current action is not allowed to be executed");
}
```

where `execution.isActive()` is an expensive operation.

For my taste, this is not readable at all... I have to stop and think, it's not immediate.

My question is about **readability** vs **efficiency**.

Comment: Why not use the ternary operator? It's simpler than the other expression, and also simpler than an if statement.

Comment: @Eran becaus it's difficult to read, I tend to avoid ternary operators when possible

Comment: @MicheleMariotti the ternary is *far* easier to read than the first approach.

Comment: @Kayaman no this is not homework. This is a *mental* homework, just for my brain sake :)

Comment: You trying to evaluate `a` only once sounds like `a` is actually a somewhat expensive operation (unless this is homework) so you might want to consider using a local variable. Evaluating a simple variable like in the case above is not very costly and probably even optimized by the compiler so I'd not bother with `a` being evaluated twice.

Comment: I agree with Andy, the ternary is way easier to read than the `t1` version.

Comment: @downvoter: i really don't understand a downvote... my question is clear and don't seem to be silly

Comment: Unrelated: what's your problem with homeworks?? xD

Answer (score 2):

In real life, if a was actually the result of an expensive call, I'd just extract it to a variable.

change this:

```
boolean t1 = (expensiveCall() && b) || (!expensiveCall() && c);
```

to this:

```
boolean result = expensiveCall();
boolean t1 = (result && b) || (!result && c);
```

But apart from that: I don't see anything wrong with using the ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

If i want the code easier to read, I'd rather do like this:

```
    private boolean isIllegalAction(execution,sourceStep,currentStep){
        return execution.isActive() ? !Objects.equals(sourceStep, currentStep) : sourceStep != null;
    }

    if(isIllegalAction(...)){
        //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question is about readability vs efficiency

Very well.

- Readability.  There are many situations in which in-lining if-then-else blocks can lead to improved readability of code.

Consider:

```
int result = (myObject.isCompleted())
        ? myObject.getStandardError()
        : myObject.computeStandardError().getStandardError();
```

... compared to:

```
int result = 0;
if (myObject.isCompleted()) {
    result = myObject.getStandardError();
}
else {
    result = myObject.computeStandardError().getStandardError();
}
```

I would say the in-lined if-then-else is much more readable, wouldn't you?

- Efficiency.  The difference in processing time between a logically equivalent inline if-then-else and a if-then-else block (if any) is almost certain to be vanishingly small and not important in real world applications.  Therefore, you choose the structure that yields the best readability.  In many cases, this is the ternary operator ... but not all cases.

Comment: No doubt when it's a direct assignation, and I agree with you that's the best for most cases. But for chained evaluation (see my real world example) it's not so obvious :)

Comment: @MicheleMariotti: "chained evaluation", as you say it, is not new or unique to the ternary operator.  Whether an expensive evaluation is repeated in a block or in-lined in a ternary operator, the result would be the same.  The performance difference between a "logically equivalent" in-line or block if-then-else will still be vanishingly small.   The typically used optimization in blocks where the result of an expensive optimization is repeatedly used is to cache the result as illustrated by Sean Patrick Floyd.